# Nonlinear ordinary differential equation (Elsgolts)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please, help me to solve the following non-linear ODEs:
\begin{align}
\tag 1 y &= (y')^4 -(y')^3 -2 \\
\tag 2 y' &= \dfrac{y}{x+ y^3}
\end{align}
Thanks.

Comment: Notice that $u^4-u^3-2 \equiv (u+1)(u^3-2u^2+2u-2)$.

Comment: @user84933: Do you have thoughts on the problem and can share what you have tried? Regards

Comment: The Maple command $$dsolve(diff(y(x), x) = y(x)/(x+y(x)^3)) $$ produces two solutions. One of them is $$y(x) =1/3\,\sqrt [3]{27\,x+3\,\sqrt {24\,{{\it \_C1}}^{3
}+81\,{x}^{2}}}-2\,{\frac {{\it \_C1}}{\sqrt [3]{27\,x+3\,\sqrt {24\,{
{\it \_C1}}^{3}+81\,{x}^{2}}}}}
 $$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the second one, let's write it as follows:
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=x'(y)=\frac{x+y^3}{y}$$
So we have this ODE instead:
$$x'-\frac{1}{y}x=y^2$$

Answer (score 6):

$$ y = y'^4 - y'^3 - 2 $$

$$ y' = p \Rightarrow y = p^4 - p^3 - 2 $$

$$ \Rightarrow y' = p = p^2(4p-3)\frac{dp}{dx} $$

$$ \Rightarrow p(4p-3) \ dp = dx \Rightarrow \int 4p^2 - 3p \ dp = \int dx $$

$$ \Rightarrow \frac{4p^3}{3} - \frac{3p^2}{2} + c_1 = x $$

$$  \Rightarrow  \left\{\begin{matrix}
y = p^4 - p^3 - 2 \\ 
\frac{4p^3}{3} - \frac{3p^2}{2} + c_1 = x  \\
\end{matrix}\right. $$